# Proof $-(x+y) = (-x) + (-y) = -x + -y$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

This was left as an exercise in Apostol's Calculus Vol II and I'm not very sure how to proceed and have my doubts on whether the following would be sufficient due to step $(1)$:
$$-(x+y) \stackrel{(1)}{=} -1(x+y) \stackrel{(2)}{=} -1x + -1y \stackrel{(3)}{=} (-x) + (-y) = -x-y$$

Where $(2)$ is allowed by the distributive multiplication property for addition in V and $(3)$ is allowed because $(-a)x = -(ax)$, which is proven by:

Let $z = (-a)x$
$$ z + ax = (-a)x + ax \stackrel{(a)}{=} (-a + a)x = 0x \stackrel{(b)}{=} O $$
Where $(a)$ is allowed by the distributive multiplication property for scalars addition and $(b)$ is true because $0x = O$ (I'm not providing this proof here, but it can be assumed already proven). We find that $z$ is the negative of $ax$ and so $z = -(ax)$.

Would this be a sufficient proof?

Comment: What makes you think that $(-1)x=-x$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Because $1$ is the multiplicative identity, so $(x + y) = 1(x+y)$ which would mean that due to the proof provided at the bottom $-(1(x+y)) = -1(x+y)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply say

-(x+y)=-(x+y)+x-x+y-y=-(x+y)+(x+y)-x-y (since we add x-x and y-y there is no problems)

which then would imply -(x+y)=-x-y

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $(x + y) - (x + y) = 0$ but we also have $x + y - x - y = 0$. Hence we have $(x + y) - (x + y) = x + y - x - y = (x + y) - x - y$. This can be reduced to $(x + y) - (x+y) = (x + y) -x -y$. Then simply cancel and we reach $-(x + y) = -x - y$.

I'm assuming that you've proven the uniqueness of inverses in a vector space and the additive cancellation rule.